# Скорость выполнения js скрипта

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт "ход конем".

В нем интервал между ходом коня (400). Скрипт начинает свое выполнение с клика по кнопке "Старт". [image: Пример]

Хочу создать 2 кнопки "button" +50 и -50 (к скорости выполнения скрипта, до запуска, клика по "Старт"), только опыта не хватает. Как стандартное значение 400 , пользователю можно изменить с 400 с ходом в +-50 от 50 до 600 ?

```
function horse() {
  //..... code

  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    nextStep();
  },400);
}
```

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// начальное значение задержки
let delay = 400; 

// функция цикла через установку таймаута на каждой итерации 
function loop() {
  nextStep(); 
  setTimeout(loop, delay);
}

// функция увеличения/уменьшения задержки 
const incDelay = x => delay = Math.min(600, Math.max(50, delay + x)); 

// обработчики клика по кнопкам уменьшения и увеличения скорости
btnSlower.addEventListener('click', () => incDelay(50)); 
btnFaster.addEventListener('click', () => incDelay(-50));
```

При таком подходе, необходимо учитывать время выполнения синхронного кода - фактически, это время неявно "добавляется" к указанному значению задержки.
То есть, интервал цикла будет примерно равен сумме `delay` и времени выполнения `nextStep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Изменить интервал работы `setInterval` нельзя.

Соответственно, надо остановить старый `setInterval` и запустить новый `setInterval` с новым значением.

```js
function horse(time) {
  //..... code
  // Очищаем предыдущий setInterval
  if (horse.interval) {
    clearInterval(horse.interval);
  }
  horse.interval = setInterval(() => {
    nextStep();
  }, time);
}

function nextStep() {
  console.log('step', intervalTime);
}

let intervalTime = 400;

function changeInterval(value) {
  intervalTime += value;
  horse(intervalTime);
}

horse(intervalTime);
```

```html
<button onclick="changeInterval(50)">+50</button>
<button onclick="changeInterval(-50)">-50</button>
```